# Receive message when consumer is up in spring-cloud-stream app

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am playing with Spring-cloud-stream and RabbitMQ.

I have a REST endpoint which produces the messages.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(MyProcessor.class)
public class ProducerDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class ProducerController {

    @Autowired
    MyProcessor myProcessor;

    @RequestMapping(value = "sendmessage/{message}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sendMessage(@PathVariable("message") String message) {
        myProcessor.anOutput().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
        return "sent";  
    }

}

interface MyProcessor {
    String INPUT = "myInput";

    @Output("myOutput")
    MessageChannel anOutput();
}
```

Through another application I am consuming these messages.

```
@StreamListener(MyProcessor.INPUT)
public void eventHandler(String message) {
    System.out.println("**************  Message received => "+message);
}
```

When both applications are UP and running. I am able to publish the message and consume it at the consumer.

The problem I am facing in the following scenario: 
 
**I am purposefully making the consumer down and publishing the message through the producer. Now when the consumer starts it is receiving no message.** 
I suppose RabbitMQ guarantees message delivery.

Github links
https://github.com/govi20/producer-demo
https://github.com/govi20/consumer-demo

Comment: Can you post your app on Github so we can take a look? There is something missing from what you've provided above. For example, `String INPUT = "myInput";` - I don't see and `@Input` configuration, etc

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky I've added GitHub links in original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned before, you already have miss-configuration in 'myInput' since you don't have `@Input` configuration which results in `A component required a bean named 'myInput' that could not be found.` error during consumer startup. 
So, something like this would be required on hte consumer side

```
 interface MyProcessor {
    String INPUT = "myInput";

    @Input("myInput")
    MessageChannel myInput();
}
```

Further more if you don't define a `group` it results in anonymous queue on the Rabbit side (something like this `myInput.anonymous.pZg03h0zQ2-SHLh1_QL8DQ`) which essentially results in a different name of the queue every time you start, so

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myInput.destination=myInput
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myInput.group=myGroup
```

will result in queue name `myInput.myGroup` which is persistent and consistent between startups.

Also, on the producer side `myOutput` results in creation of a Rabbit Exchange that has no routing to the aforementioned (or any other) queue, therefore Rabbit drops messages, so you can't possibly be receiving messages originated from the producer until you create a route between the `myOutput` exchange and the `myInput.myGroup` queue. 
However, if you configure the input as I described above, spring-cloud-stream will also create an exchange called `myInput` which will be automatically routed to `myInput.myGroup`, so if you change your producer to send to that destination you will receive messages on the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a group on the consumer input binding. Otherwise it is anonymous and binds an auto delete queue, which only exists while the consumer is running.

Comment: I don't know what you mean and it seems unrelated to this question. The admins here don't like extended commentary. Ask a new question if there is something else you need.

Comment: Also, feel free to go through the extensive library of samples we provide https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Thanks for sharing the link.